# Error dataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying  to use datatables plugin, but i get an error when calling the function dataTable().
My code looks like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tableID').dataTable();
    });
</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run it, I can see an error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
$('#tableID').dataTable();
```

In Firebug I can see the jquery.dataTables.js file included, but the function dataTable() doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a function called `dataTable()` in your js file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case:
I was including

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

twice in the page: at header and before `</body>`
When I removed one them, problem has gone away

Answer (score 9):

for me works move definition out of box

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tableID').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tableID').dataTable();
</script>
```

and it Works perfectly.